# Android intent to pick file not running activity

Tags: android, android-intent, filechooser

I have a problem with intents in Android. In my project, I'd like to open file using one of the installed file managers. I'm creating my intent and it invokes option to choose which file manager to start and starts this file manager, but I don't see any changes in logs , like it wouldn't really start this activity. I'm new to Android, so any help would be welcome.
My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/aB0rQWFs), and my logs from logcat are [here](http://hastebin.com/enidedixog.avrasm).
For testing I'm using Genymotion 2.5.0, with Google Nexus 4 - 4.1.1 Android - API 16.
Thanks in advance
**EDIT**
Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Intent.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int PICK_FILE = -1;
    String sciezka = "cos na poczatek";
    private static final String TAG1 = "TAG1_INTENT";
    private static final String TAG2 = "TAG2_ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pickFile();
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(sciezka);
        setContentView(tv);


    }

    private void pickFile(){
        //Toast.makeText(this, sciezka, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG1, "Tworzenie nowego intenta");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Log.d(TAG1, "ustawianie typow");
        intent.setType("*/*");
        Log.d(TAG1, "ustawienie akcji na get_content");
        intent.setAction(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Log.d(TAG1, "Odpalanie intenta");
        try{
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Wybierz plik"), PICK_FILE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Zainstaluj przeglądarke plików", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Log.d(TAG1, "Brak przeglądarki plików");
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG1, "No odpalenie intenta nie zadziałało");
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "nanana batman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
        Log.d(TAG2, "Pierwszy if - reqCode == PICK_FILE");
        if(reqCode == PICK_FILE){
            Log.d(TAG2, "Drugi if - resCode == RESULT_CANCELED");
            if(resCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Log.d(TAG2, "wywolanie RESULT_CANCELED - na pewno ok?");
            }

            if(resCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.d(TAG2, "No to jestesmy w resCode == RESULT_OK, pobieranie danych o selectedFile, tworzenie uri selectedFile");
                Uri selectedFile = null;
                Log.d(TAG2, "proba pobrania danych do selectedFile");
                try{
                    selectedFile = data.getData();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG2, "Cos nie zabanglalo i nie pobralo info");
                }
                Log.d(TAG2, "dane pobralo poprawnie, ustawianie path na sciezeczka");
                String path = "sciezeczka";
                Log.d(TAG2, "proba pobrania sciezeczki do pliczku");
                try{
                    path = getFilePath(getApplicationContext(), selectedFile);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG2, "nope, nie pobralo sciezki");
                    path = "No i kiszka";
                }
                Log.d(TAG2, "wypisanie patha");
                System.out.println(path);

            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG2, "No i pierwszy if nie byl true");
        }
        Log.d(TAG2, "wyswietlenie toasta - tylko z czym?");
        Toast.makeText(this, sciezka, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri){

        return "cos";
    }
}
```

Logs

```
07-17 07:01:58.966    1838-1838/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-17 07:01:59.030    1838-1838/? D/TAG1_INTENT﹕ Tworzenie nowego intenta
07-17 07:01:59.030    1838-1838/? D/TAG1_INTENT﹕ ustawianie typow
07-17 07:01:59.030    1838-1838/? D/TAG1_INTENT﹕ ustawienie akcji na get_content
07-17 07:01:59.030    1838-1838/? D/TAG1_INTENT﹕ Odpalanie intenta
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13330: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 408: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 430: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-17 07:01:59.038    1838-1838/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-17 07:01:59.094    1838-1838/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
07-17 07:01:59.102    1838-1838/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8475aa8, tid 1838
07-17 07:01:59.118    1838-1838/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
07-17 07:01:59.118    1838-1838/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
07-17 07:01:59.314    1838-1838/? W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 07:01:59.334    1838-1838/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-17 07:01:59.366    1838-1842/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 3% free 10943K/11207K, paused 27ms+0ms, total 30ms
07-17 07:02:00.054    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb842a868): name, size, mSize = 2, 4096, 4096
07-17 07:02:00.122    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb837c798): name, size, mSize = 4, 9216, 13312
07-17 07:02:00.274    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 07:02:00.290    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8405fd8): name, size, mSize = 6, 33792, 47104
07-17 07:02:00.298    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8432268): name, size, mSize = 8, 33792, 80896
07-17 07:02:00.298    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb83fd9a8): name, size, mSize = 9, 36864, 117760
07-17 07:02:00.298    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb84ff110): name, size, mSize = 10, 36864, 154624
07-17 07:02:00.302    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb84ffca0): name, size, mSize = 11, 33856, 188480
07-17 07:02:00.306    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8500658): name, size, mSize = 12, 36864, 225344
07-17 07:03:50.262    1838-1838/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8414f18): name, size, mSize = 32, 576, 225920
07-17 07:06:58.990    1838-1842/pl.filemanagerinvoker D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 3% free 11232K/11527K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 4ms
```

Comment: Please add your code and logcat in the question.

Comment: It's in the links, 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: I know. Add them along with the question and not as links. Your links might not be accessible to some people because of various reasons (e.g Firewall).

Comment: Which file manager are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to use file Manager from Genymotion thats installed on their VMs. I'm getting the window to actually choose which file manager I want to use and it starts, but I don't see anything in my logs that starts with `TAG2`. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/gGU8sVd.png) is screen of what I see after my VM starts. In red circle I've marked what File manager I'm using.

Comment: You will get something in your logs after you select the file from the file manager and return back to your application.

Comment: @PrerakSola I don't really know how to do that. I've been looking through stack and Android documentation, but I couldn't figure anything really. [I've made this thing](http://hastebin.com/dajituruci.avrasm) but it still gives same output in logs. I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I don't really know what. Probably newbie mistake.

Comment: Just select a file from the file explorer and see what happens after that.

Comment: @PrerakSola I can select file from explorer, but still I don't have anything from logs that start with `TAG2_ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT`. Last thing I see is `D/TAG1_INTENT﹕ Odpalanie intenta`.
I couldn't respond earlier, sorry.

Comment: What happens after you select a file? You are redirected to your application or something else happens?

Comment: @PrerakSola After choosing file I'm back to my activity screen with `TextView` `cos na poczatek`. Nothing from `onActivityResult` in logs.

Comment: @PrerakSola I've managed to fix the problem. Part of my mistake was doing everything in one `Activity`. After splitting it to 2 activities I'm now able to get path to file from file manager. Thank you for your help & time.

Comment: I am glad, you managed to solve it on your own. Happy coding... :)